# Density of $C^k$-functions with Lipschitz partial derivatives

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, mg.metric-geometry

Let $N$ and $M$ be complete Riemannian manifolds, of respective dimension $n$ and $m$ with $n,m\geq 1$.  Let $C^{k,1}_b(N,M)$ be set of all bounded continuous functions $f:N\rightarrow M$ for which the following is finite:
$$
\max_{\beta:|\beta|\leq k}
\max_{x \in N}\, \|D^k f(x)\|
+
\sup_{x,y\in N\, x\neq y}\, \frac{\|D^kf(x)-D^kf(y)\|}{d_Y(x,y)}
.
$$

I know that if $k=0$, then in a paper of Ambrosio it was shown that $C^{0,1}(N,M)$ is dense in $C(N,M)$ (for the compact-convergence topology).  The Weirestrass theorem also shows that $C^{\infty}(N,M)$ is also dense in $C(N,M)$.

Therefore, I wonder, is it true that $C^{k,1}_b(N,M)$ is dense in $C_b(N,M)$ for $k\geq \max\{n,m\}$?

*Here, I'm wondering about the uniform topology topology.*

Comment: Before anyone can answer your question, you need to clarify in what sense you want that density to be. Uniform convergence on compact sets? Uniform convergence on $N$?...

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz I added the clarification

Comment: @JohnWayLCS I modified your statement for the $C_b$ spaces and the uniform topology, since it is obvious that it holds uniformly on compacts by considering $C^{k+1}$-compactly supported functions and applying the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem. I hope that's ok.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  Sure then let's take that form of the question.  Also thanks for pointing that out!